# Why is timing wrong when reading infra red signal

Tags: timer, arduino, infrared

I was trying to read infra red signal from arduino so I wrote this code

```
{
  long int initial = micros();
  int timeinms = millis();
  int oldValue = 0;
  int bitPosition = 0;
  
  while(millis() - timeinms< 100){
    int value = (PIND  & B10000000 ) >> 7;
    if(value != oldValue){
      oldValue = value;
      arr[bitPosition] = micros() > initial ? micros() - initial : 4294967295 - initial + micros();
      bitVal[bitPosition] = value;
      bitPosition++;
    }
   
   }
}
```

But when I read signal I get the general timing is correct 430 and 600 instead of 562 and 1620 instead of 562 * 3 but why is there such difference. I know micros has 4 microseconds error but this should result to at most 8 microseconds error not 80 or 100

So what is the problem is it a bug in the code or something I am missing

Tried above code getting times with + or - 80 microseconds to 100

Comment: `micros()` return an `unsigned long`, not `long`. You would get unexpected results when you mix unsigned with signed values. Same for `millis()`, so `int timeinms = millis();` narrow cast the unsigned long to a 16-bit int. Turn on your compiler warning (Arduino => Preferences => show verbase output during: compilation), you will make less mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how `millis` is working in background. Your code is interrupted every 1 millisecond by timer. I guess that duration of ISR is explanation of observed differentiae of time measurement. Don't use `millis` you get more precise time measurement. Or use other timer in capture mode for most precise measurement.

Comment: But I am only using millis to read for 100 ms however all my calculations are using micros which should only has 4 microseconds error not 80

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times `millis` is used and where. Your code is interrupted every 1ms at random place and Interrupt Service Routine associated with Timer is executed for calculating elapsed time.

Comment: Ok but I also tried a logic analyzer sometimes getting times of 530 and 570 microseconds which are close enough to real value and some times I am getting 600 and 400

Comment: Than your measurements is OK and it is hw problem, or IR protocol behavior.

Comment: Yes but why, what if I am reversing a new protocol that is unkown how will I replay data at correct timings if timings are wrong now. I am also interested in the why. And how to fix it

Comment: This is not the right place for hw troubleshooting. My approach for reversing IR protocol is connect Si photodiod to digital osciloscope, record whole IR datagram and then measure all values (carrier frequency, modulation..)

Comment: What do you mean h.w troubleshooting, it is just a hobby. And I dont have an osciloscope so I used a logical analyzer but there are fluctuations in timings recieved

Comment: I mean hardware issue. This site is related strictly to software issues. This fluctuation is on same command? Can you provide whole OK and NG IR command recorded by LA?

Comment: Better site for [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com) issue